# Wordpress plugin Relevanssi erroring out of the blue

Tags: php, wordpress

We are using Relevanssi on one of our sites and it stopped working all of a sudden. Unfortunately I am only one of the admins and I wouldn't know if anyone updated anything recently to that extent but when using Relevanssi's debuggin, this is what I see:

```
"Notice: Use of undefined constant research - assumed 'research' in /var/www/html/aromaticscience.com/wp-content/plugins/widget-logic/widget_logic.php(286) : eval()'d code on line 1

Notice: Undefined offset: 3361 in /var/www/html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/reorder-posts-within-categories.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined offset: 3361 in /var/www/html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/reorder-posts-within-categories.php on line 84

Notice: Undefined offset: 3361 in /var/www/html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/reorder-posts-within-categories.php on line 131"
```

Also, the search returns "Sorry, No Results. Try your search again." even when certain sure words are used. Something must be disconnected.

I am not a WordPress pro at all. Please advise.

Comment: [Contact the developers of the plugin.](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/relevanssi)

Comment: I sure did. Got a discussion going.